# Why isn't my variable getting passed in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

what am I missing? I want to get a variable which is incremented in JavaScript and pass it to PHP via AJAX. Maybe you can help me with my code?

```js
function increase()
{
    var k=1;
 k++;
 

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'inc/functions.php',
      data: ({page:k}),
      success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
      }
    });
}

function decrease()
{
 var k=1;
 k--;

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'inc/functions.php',
      data: ({page:k}),
      success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
      }
    });
}
```

This function should be triggered when I am pressing the button on an "onclick" event.

This variable which is "k" should be passed to inc/functions.php

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
echo $temp;
```

What am I doing wrong?
I need the variable because for use in the following MySQL statement.

```
$sql_tbl_questions = "SELECT * FROM `questions` where istAktiv='1' && dimension=$page";
```

The idea is : the user presses "next" then the JS is incrementing the variable by 1 passing it to my function where the "table" is getting to the next "site".

Comment: lose the `()`. just `data: {page:k},`

Comment: Could you post the full relevant code and not just your JS functions?

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and where is $temp being declared?

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP request/response in the browser , that will give you more insight into what request is being made.

`ctl+shift+c` in mozila

Answer (score 1):

your increment variable should be outside the function, otherwise k is always 2

```js
var ki = kd = 1;
function increase()
{
  ki++;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    data: {'page':ki},
    success: function(response) {
      content.html(response);
    }
  });
}

function decrease()
{
  kd--;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    data: {'page':kd},
    success: function(response) {
      content.html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet for increment

```
var k = 1
function increase() {
    var dataForAjaxCall = { page: k++ };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/functions.php',
        data: dataForAjaxCall,
        success: function(response) {
        content.html(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Similarly you can write for decrement also. 
NB: Make sure you initialize the decrement counter variable outside of the function like given above